# Using long query method instead of short method for creating database

Tags: android, android-studio

If I want to create a table

Many programmers and many of the answers for creating SQLite database uses this method.

1st method

```
 private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
       "CREATE TABLE " + contacts + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + name + " TEXT," + age + " TEXT)";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + contacts;
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

using database helper class and etc etc.

but I use this method

2nd method

```
   db=openOrCreateDatabase("Details",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,name VARCHAR,age VARCHAR,);");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO contacts (name,age) VALUES('Deepak','age');");
Cursor v= db.rawQuery("Select * from contacts where name='Deepak'",null);
```

Can anyone please tell that this 2nd query method will create any type of problem so that I will soon use the 1st long method.

Comment: I think remove +.

Comment: You can use the 2nd method too.